# Someone who takes inspirational quotes seriously

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a name for someone who takes inspiration and other quotes too seriously or to heart?

Comment: Maybe *sappy* or *simpy*?

Comment: Maybe naïve or gullible ?

Comment: *"I never said half the things people say I did"* - Albert Einstein.   *"Don’t believe everything you read on the Internet just because there’s a picture with a quote next to it.”* – Abraham Lincoln

Comment: Clearly the word that applies to someone who takes inspirational quotes seriously is *inspired*. And someone who takes them too seriously is *overinspired*.

Comment: @drew Overly Inspired, then. Seems like a popular term on the internet.

Comment: "suggestible" may fit, but don't specifically refers to quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [credulous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/credulous). Someone who is credulous will believe anything anyone wants him to believe.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say such a person is [susceptible](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/susceptible) or [impressionable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/impressionable).

susceptible

> Likely or liable to be influenced or harmed by a particular thing:
>   *'patients with liver disease may be susceptible to infection'*

impressionable

> Easily influenced:
>   *'a girl of eighteen is highly impressionable'*

No direct connotation with quotes, though.

References:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/susceptible
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/impressionable